# I keep getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and I have no idea why

Tags: java

I keep getting the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` in the line that says 
`winVals[i] = rand`, but i have no idea why.

```
int valueCount = 5;
int theLimit = 5;
int[] winVals = new int[valueCount];
Random r = new Random();
int rand = 0;
for(int i= 0; i < winVals.length; i++)
{
    rand = r.nextInt(theLimit - 1) +1;
    if(i == 0)
    {
        winVals[0] = rand;
    }
    else if (i > 0)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < winVals.length; j++)
        { 
           if( winVals[j] == rand)
           {
              i--;
           }      
           else
           {
               winVals[i] = rand;
           }
        }
    }
}
for(int i=0; i < valueCount; i++)
{
    System.out.println(winVals[i]);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried printing out the value of `i` at that point?

Comment: Decrementing the `for` loop counter in the body of the loop. Usually not a good idea...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for (int j = 0; j < winVals.length; j++)
{ 
   if( winVals[j] == rand)
       i--;
   else
   {
       winVals[i] = rand;
   }
}
```

In this section you're looping through values of `j` and decreasing `i`, but you're not bothering to check if `i` is still valid. What if `i` is 1 and you decrease it twice?

Comment: Also, in a loop I would not change the value of the variable being increased; while it may be legit it is not very used and hard to notice by other programmers, I would use a `while` for these situations (IMHO)

Answer (score 1):

You decrement the loop counter inside the loop:

```
if( winVals[j] == rand)
     i--;
```

which leads to out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

I think this line is the problem.

```
   if( winVals[j] == rand)
     i--;
```

Think if before this line, i=0 and j=0, and this condition becomes true, **i becomes, -1**

Answer (score 0):

Just tested it , because of the above mentioned where the index is decremented, this runs in an endless loop.